# Hapi: How to send image

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have a jpeg image binary, How can I use Hapi to show the image? My code only shows garbage to the end user of the API.

```
hapiServer.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path:'/users/{userId}/photo',
  handler: async function (request, reply) {
    const userId = parseInt(encodeURIComponent(request.params.userId));


    const photo = getImageBinary(userId);    
    reply(photo);
  }
});
```

Comment: how is this API called. What does getImageBinary return?

Comment: @JaromandaX The user enters www.host.com/users/123/photo and the browser shows the photo, getImageBinary returns binary data of the image

Comment: A content type header should help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your picture binary data is `png`:

```
hapiServer.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path:'/users/{userId}/photo',
  handler: async function (request, reply) {
    const userId = parseInt(encodeURIComponent(request.params.userId));

    const photo = getImageBinary(userId);    
    reply(photo).header('Content-Disposition','inline').header('Content-type','image/png');
  }
});
```